# Grub install on usb stick by accident/can't load Windows without the stick anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount

I installed ubuntu 16.04 on a usb drive. My objective is to have my laptop running with Windows 7 (already installed) and when needed start the computer with the usb stick plugged in, press F9 and chose to run the usb stick.

But now if the USB stick isn't plugged in i have an error message that GRUB is missing. So it left me with 2 questions:
- where to put grub: I want it in the internal drive /sda, which has two partition: system (/sda1) and OSDisk (/sda2). I have seen in similar thread that i could run:

> sudo grub-install /dev/sda

But should I specify sda1, sda2 or just sda?

- I don't want grub at all, since when the usb stick isn't plugged i just want windows to run directly. Is there any possibility to do that? That question may very stupid but i don't understand much about what happens at the start of turning on the laptop. I would like that if i don't press F9 and start from the usb drive, windows initiate directly.

Thanks a lot for the help!

PS: My laptop is HP elitebook 840 and here is the result of sudo fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

...

Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 167.7 GiB, 180045766656 bytes, 351651888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x44914633

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1023999   1021952   499M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       1024000 351649839 350625840 167.2G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdb: 14.7 GiB, 15795748864 bytes, 30851072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 30849023 30846976 14.7G 83 Linux
```

Comment: You need Grub to boot Linux. It sounds like you overwrite your Windows bootloader in the MBR of `sda` with Grub. You should boot into Ubuntu and run `sudo grub-install sdb`  to install Grub in the MBR of `sdb`, after doing that reinstall Windows bootloader in the MBR of `sda`. Then change BIOS boot-order to `sdb` first and `sda` second, so you will automatically boot to Ubuntu when the external drive is connected.

Comment: Thanks, any tip on how to  reinstall windows bootloader?

Comment: Just google `Reinstall Win7 bootloader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: After some search based on the useful answers below, here is my solution.

- GRUB messed up with the mbr and being stored on the usb stick, i couldn't load windows without the usb stick.
- So i created a windows system recovery bootable usb (don't have CD/DVD on my notebook) and used first startup repare, but didn't work, then command prompt and bootrec /fixmbr. The last one worked!!! This this post for more details.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/

- Now I run windows normally and if i want ubuntu i insert the USB stick with my ubuntu, press F9 when the computer starts, and choose to boot from the usb stick.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing),

> Reinstalling GRUB 2 from a Working System
>
> If Ubuntu is operating normally, boot into the working installation
>   and run the following command from a terminal.
>
> X is the drive (letter) on which you want GRUB to write the boot information. Normally users should not include a partition number,
>   which would produce an error message as the command would attempt to
>   write the information to a partition.
>
> ```
> sudo grub-install /dev/sdX  # Example: sudo grub-install /dev/sda
> ```
>
> This will rewrite the MBR information to point to the current
>   installation and rewrite some GRUB 2 files (which are already
>   working). Since it isn't done during execution of the previous
>   command, running sudo update-grub after the install will ensure GRUB
>   2's menu is up-to-date.

Comment: I have tried the same but have failed always. One option for you is go into BIOS and put Windows boot manager as the top entry . Now when you need to boot into ubuntu plug in the usb stick and select ubuntu entry from BIOS

Comment: Yes i tried to install grub on sda but doesn't solve the issue. Will reinstall it on sdb and check your solution. Thanks

Comment: Pranal Narayan, how do I "go into BIOS and put Windows boot manager as the top entry"?

Comment: Feldspar answer is a correct answer to my question but does NOT solve the issue. See my update.